# excel 2010 -- need formula to make a calculation for x rows only

Tags: excel-formula

How do i write a formula to set the contents of a cell to a value (e.g. the number 215) for the next x rows?  (I want to avoid macros and vba coding.)

Answer (score 0):

That isn't something that a formula can really do.  A formula is only able to act upon the value of the cell in which it is contained. You will need to use VBA I'm afraid.

If you are okay with having to fill all the cells that *might* have values, you can use something like this:

http://1drv.ms/1myu7fg

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to be able to use an IF statement to check whether the X rows had been completed.  For example, say X = 120.  I would put the IF statement in ALL rows and ask whether the row I am on is less than or greater than row 120.  I just don't know how to ask excel (using a formula) what row i am on.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There you go! Check out my example.

Answer (score 0):

Type this formula into cell B1

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<$E$1,"X","")
```

You'll notice it refernces E1. In that cell, type a number, e.g. 5.

The formula basically looks to see what the row number is and then checks if it's less than what you typed in E1 (e.g. 5).

If it is less, it'll display X, if it's not, it'll be blank.

You can replace "X" with whatever you need displayed. You can change the value in E1 as you need to.